# Capital Losses from more than 3 years ago unclaimed

Tags: united-states, income-tax, capital-loss

I had capital losses from 2014, 2015, and 2016, but here it is 2020 and I haven't claimed any capital gains or losses on my US tax returns since then. Is there anything I can do to get a benefit from this now?

I had about 80, 30, 30 loss for each of those years and I had no gains. I wanted to just save the capital losses for when I did have some gains (I had no gains until 2020 this year). The gains in 2020 are about 20k. Can I avoid claiming the 3000 against income and just carry forward everything year after year?

I was doing some research and I saw that
"You can amend a return at any time, but you can generally only claim a refund for up to 3 years from the date the return was due or 2 years from the date the tax was paid. "

Doing a little more research I see "The tax law says you have to use a capital loss before you're allowed to use a personal exemption." Does this mean I would be able to amend a return from 2014, 2015, 2016, even though the deadline is past to receive a refund for those years in order to update the carry forward after reducing it by 3000 in each of those years?

Comment: There’s not enough information to answer you. You should have taken losses against any gains. If no gains, then $3000 of loss against ordinary income. What happened in 2017, 18, 19? Did you not take the appropriate loss each year?

Comment: Concur with JTP; if you didn't do this correctly, you are now within the 3-year window to amend 2017, 2018, and 2019 returns. To avoid errors, wait for each one to process before doing the next -- once, long ago, I didn't and got stuck in Appeals for two years.

Comment: Got it. Welcome to Money.SE, note that comments often get long/many and deleted easily. I edited your comments into the question. You are welcome to re-edit if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use Dave's comment/advice. Starting with 2014, create the amended return. Do it right, if there were no gains, $3000 of the loss goes against ordinary income. The rest gets carried forward. Send it in, and they'll send a response that you are too late for that refund. Then file 2015 using the same process. You'll lose $3000 of loss for each year that's 2018 or prior. $15K out of the $140K is unfortunate, but not tragic.

Comment: I'm not from the US, so I've no idea who is right (or, whether I'm misinterpreting something), but Dave's comment says to start with amending the 201**7** return (with, to me, the implication that the three-year rule prevents going further back). Or is it that you can _amend_ that far back (without getting any refund) and this is necessary to "establish a connection" (if that's the right phrase) between the years the losses were made and the years (2017 onwards) when amend-and-refund _is_ possible?

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, one can’t ignore the missed years, $3000/yr that ‘should’ have been taken is lost. That, I’m certain of. If one starts with the return that can still get a refund, the IRS might still ask for the paper trail.

Comment: Do you actually have to take the $3000 in loss against regular income?

Comment: @TripeHound+ I read "I haven't claimed any capital gains or losses since then" to mean since 2016, implying the losses in 2014-2016 _were_ claimed (up to the $3k limit). The paragraph implying 2014-2016 need amending was added in an edit after my comment. If so, I concur OP needs to correct those first (but is too late to get any refunds) and _then_ 2017-2019 (by next April is in time to get any refunds).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You could be right; I read "_even though the deadline is past to receive a refund for those years_" (2014-16) as meaning OP _hadn't_ claimed for those years (and accepts it's too late to do so) but wants to "rescue" the loss.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - You have losses, either current or carried forward from prior year(s). Say $10K. You first take losses against this years realized gains, until those gains are reduced to zero. If there are still losses, you take up to $3K against ordinary income. Yes, if you have income, you must. (I honestly don't know the result if income is zero, I don't believe the $3K gets applied to anything and therefore, it's carried forward. My guess here)